# Failed to execute goal com.reucon.maven.plugins:maven-openfire-plugin:1. 0.2-SNAPSHOT:jspc

Tags: java, jsp, maven, xmpp, openfire

After : Inside openfire-apns-plugin directory run: **mvn clean install -X**

I am getting below error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.reucon.maven.plugins:maven-openfire-plugin:1.
0.2-SNAPSHOT:jspc (default-jspc) on project apns: Failure processing jsps -> [He
lp 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal c
om.reucon.maven.plugins:maven-openfire-plugin:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT:jspc (default-jspc)
 on project apns: Failure processing jsps
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThre
adedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Failure processing jsps

        at com.reucon.maven.plugin.openfire.jspc.JspcMojo.execute(JspcMojo.java:
202)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
BuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:208)
        ... 19 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc
eption
```

if any one have configure https://github.com/xinminlabs/openfire-apns-plugin please guide it.

Thank in advance.

Comment: so, you trying to build this plugin by yourself, right?

Comment: no i am trying to installing it.

Comment: are you following guide?

Comment: yes now it got compiled but i am facing this error "Missing database schema for apns. Attempting to install...
openfire-apns - Database update failed. Please manually upgrade your database"

Comment: please update question with that info

Answer (score 1):

you need to check two things:

1. there must be a folder **webapp** in src/main
2. The complete path should not (absolutely) have spaces

This two thing help us